# Configure Environment to Use File System Locally and Amazon on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am not sure how to configure the environment such that Carrier Wave will use the local file storage when running the app locally (development) and s3 after i load to heroku (production)

in Development storage :file

in Production  storage :s3

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Either model, or you can set it globally. Have a look at the readme for v0.5.2 (current gem) at https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/tree/v0.5.2

Near the bottom, there are some instructions for configuring the test environment. Use the same approach to use different configurations for "development" and "production", e.g. add a file "carrierwave.rb" to "config/initialisers" and add the configuration code

```
if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.cucumber?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  end
end
```

and for development

```
if Rails.env.development?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
  end
end
```

and production

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :s3
  end
end
```

Comment: in which file do i put this code? Development.rb? 
I put it in development.rb and i get an error message can't convert Symbol into Integer when i try and access avatar.url?

Comment: I would put it in "config/initializers/carrierwave.rb" (create a new file).

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I usually do is through the Uploader.

```
class CoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage (Rails.env.production? ? :fog : :file)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct one liner. This seems like a better place (in the uploader) to make this environment-based storage decision. In my case I only needed to make a distinction in one of my uploaders.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is set in a model somewhere. You could do something like

```
if Rails.env.production?
  // set production
else
  // set dev / test
end
```